# How do I install and link the correct tcl-tk for Python 3 on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos

Will someone please give a clear, precise, repeatable method of linking a brewed Python 3 with the correct tcl-tk for a Mac OS?

I am NOT a power user.

I received an answer to this question from a homebrew contributor, but that answer no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

flagging python3 on install '--with-tcl-tk' works, but the idle3 launch needs to be linked to it using brew linkapps python3.

thereafter, the warning caveat which accompanies idle3 launch disappears.

I hope this helps other users.

jA